Confused by conditional expectation calculation
Let $X$ be a random variable following a triangular distribution with pdf:
$$f(X = x) = 2x \text{,}\quad 0 \leq x \leq 1.$$
$$\hspace{0.8cm}\qquad= 0 \text{,}\quad \text{otherwise}.$$
For a given constant $0 \leq c \leq 1$, I want to calculate:
$$\mathbb{E}(X - c \mid X > c)$$
and also
$$\mathbb{E}(c - X \mid X < c).$$
I am looking for help how to do this but I am not sure how to start. In particular, I would like to write the expectations as integrals but I am not sure how to do that correctly.

Let's start with the definition of the conditional expectation of a random function $g$ on an event $A$. Here $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function of the event $A$.
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X) \mid A] = 
\frac{\mathbb{E}[g(x)\cdot\mathbf{1}_A]}{\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_A]} = 
\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\mathbf{1}_A \; f(x) \, dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_A \; f(x) \, dx}
.
$$
In your specific case:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X-c \mid X \ge c] = 
\frac{\int_{0}^{1} (x-c)\mathbf{1}_{x \ge c} \; f(x) \, dx}{\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{1}_{x \ge c} \; f(x) \, dx} =
\frac{\int_{c}^{1} (x-c)\, f(x) \, dx}{\int_{c}^{1} \, f(x) \, dx} =
\frac{\frac{2}{3}x^3-cx^2 \big|_c^1}{x^2\big|_c^1} = 
\frac{x^2(\frac{2}{3}x-c) \big|_c^1}{x^2\big|_c^1} =
\frac{1}{3}\frac{(1-c)(c+2)}{1+c}
$$
Notice, that we can check the solution by plugging some values of $c$. For instance:

if $c=0$: $\mathbb{E}[X-c \mid X \ge c] = \mathbb{E}[X\mid X] =\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{0}^{1} x\, 2x \, dx = \frac{2}{3}x^3\big|_0^1=\frac{2}{3}$.
if $c=1$: given the condition $X>c$ the only valid value for $X$ is $1$, making $X-c$ a zero. That coincides with the calculation.

The case for $\mathbb{E}[c-X \mid X \le c]$ is calculated the same way.

Thank you so much.

The answer has changed a lot. What was the bug in the first version?

There was a tiny arithmetic mistake when plugging in the limits of integration. The rest is totally fine.
